# How to split the string by last found number in the string?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to re module in python. I was trying to split the string in the last found number.

```
Given string:
![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file0.png)
                                  ^ last found number = 0


I would like to split the string in three parts:  

part1: ![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file
part2: 0
part3: .png)
```

My attempt:

I can find these splits:

```py
lst = re.split(r'(\d+)', query)
# ['![](images/folder', '0', '/subfolder', '1', '/file', '0', '.png)']
```

But, I am not sure how to split in three parts.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: How about if you do for i in range(0,10): query = '![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file'+i+'.png)' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution for your first non-edited question :

```py
import sys, re

query = "![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file0.png)"

query = re.sub("(\d+)(?!.*\d+.*)", str(int(re.search("(\d+)(?!.*\d+.*)",query).group()) + 1),query)
print(query)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead:

`(?!.*\d)` make sure we haven't a digit after.

```
query = '![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file0.png)'
lst = re.split(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)', query)
print lst
```

**Output:**

```
['![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file', '0', '.png)']
```

Comment: @milkyway001: I don't understand why you'selected the other answer that seems more compex that mine and doesn't give your expected result!!!.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(\S+)(\d+)(\.\S+)`

```
s = "![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file10.png)"
matched = re.findall(r'(\S+)(\d+)(\.\S+)', s)

# output
[('![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file1', '0', '.png)')]
```

**Edit**: As highlighted by @Toto, this will not work if there are spaces, it can be overcome by `(.+)(\d+)(\.\S+)`

```
s = "![](mages/sub folder0/sub folder1/file0.png"
matched = re.findall(r'(.+)(\d+)(\.\S+)', s)

# output
[('![](mages/sub folder0/sub folder1/file', '0', '.png')]
```

Comment: This will not work for string `![](images/sub folder0/sub folder1/file0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? If 'file'+number in the query is consistent:

```
import sys, re
query = "![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file10.png)"
num = re.findall('\d+',query)[-1] # gives last number 0

newnum = int(num)+1
query = query.replace(r'file'+num, 'file'+str(newnum))
print(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use regex? I wrote this up without using regex:

```
s = '![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file0.png)'

s1 = s.split('/')
s2 = s1[len(s1)-1].split('.')
s3 = s2[0][0:4] + str(int(s2[0][4:])+1) + '.' + s2[1]
new_filelist = []
for i in s1[0:len(s1)-1]:
    append_str = i + '/'
    new_filelist.append(append_str)
new_filelist.append(s3)
new_filename = ''.join(i for i in new_filelist)
```

This adds 1 to the last digit as long as the string always ends with 'fileXX.png'

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
import sys, re

query = "![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file0.png)"
m = re.match(r'(.+)(\d+)(.+)', query)

lst = m.groups()
print(lst)
```

Gives:

```
('![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file', '0', '.png)')
```

**Update**
Credits: @Toto

The above regex pattern only works when last number is single digit.
([try at regex101](https://regex101.com/)).

```
![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file20.png)
wrong answer ==> ('![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file2', '0', '.png)')
```

To solve this problem use negative look around:

```
query = '![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file20.png)'
lst = re.split(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)', query)

right answer ==> ('![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file', '20', '.png)')
```

Comment: This will not work for string `![](images/folder0/subfolder1/file20.png)`